# jQuery global variable, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is this simple global variable not working inside a function

```
var test_1 = "None";
$(function(){
    console.log(test_1)
})
```

I am getting the result `Undefined`

Comment: Maybe you don't have jQuery?

Comment: but this is working: var test_1 = "None" console.log(test_1)

Comment: The $ variable will be equal to `jQuery` if the library is loaded on your page. Try this: `jQuery(function() { console.log(test_1); })`. If you get an error that jQuery is not defined, that's your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check, whether you have jquery or not. I have created a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/2kudvsr0/) for your code and its printing `None` (desired output).

Just make sure you are executing your code once jQuery is imported successfully.

Comment: Thanks Vika, there was an issue with my jQuery.